# Someone please help me compress this formula - Compiled formula exceeds 5000

Tags: formula-field, if

Someone please help me compress this formula - Compiled formula exceeds 5000

```
IF(Today()<Date(Year(Today()),7,1), 
Case((Year(Pledge_Submitted_Date__c)+YearsToGo__c) -Year(Today()), 
4, US_School__r.X8th_Grade_Status__c, 
5, US_School__r.X7th_Grade_Status__c, 
6, US_School__r.X6th_Grade_Status__c, 
7, US_School__r.X5th_Grade_Status__c,
8, US_School__r.X4th_Grade_Status__c, 
9, US_School__r.X3rd_Grade_Status__c, 
10, US_School__r.X2nd_Grade_Status__c, 
11, US_School__r.X1st_Grade_Status__c, 
12, US_School__r.Kindergarten_Grade_Status__c, 
'Graduated'), 
Case((Year(Pledge_Submitted_Date__c)+YearsToGo__c) -Year(Today()), 
5, US_School__r.X8th_Grade_Status__c, 
6, US_School__r.X7th_Grade_Status__c, 
7, US_School__r.X6th_Grade_Status__c, 
8, US_School__r.X5th_Grade_Status__c,
9, US_School__r.X4th_Grade_Status__c, 
10, US_School__r.X3rd_Grade_Status__c, 
11, US_School__r.X2nd_Grade_Status__c, 
12, US_School__r.X1st_Grade_Status__c, 
13, US_School__r.Kindergarten_Grade_Status__c, 
'Graduated'))
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say, David.

Comment: I am pretty confused. David didn't post any comment. But also, it is unclear where he got the formula from that he edited in.

Comment: So it looks like you're just trying to render a value on a student record based on what year they are in currently - However, i am not sure that this formula could be shortened given that you want to put up a status text. Is it necessary to use such formula versus evaluating in trigger and storing the value where it is not accurate based on your criteria. since this is a 1 time every 12 month field change - why not just update the record when YearsToGo__c is updated?

Comment: @AdrianLarson The lack of space between `<` and `Date` caused SFSE to consider it close enough to the start of an html tag, and prevented the rest from being rendered. The "source" or "side by side markdown" options in the edit history show the rest of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Case(((Year(Pledge_Submitted_Date__c)+YearsToGo__c) - Year(Today())) + 
IF(Today()<Date(Year(Today()),7,1), 1, 0),
5, US_School__r.X8th_Grade_Status__c, 
6, US_School__r.X7th_Grade_Status__c, 
7, US_School__r.X6th_Grade_Status__c, 
8, US_School__r.X5th_Grade_Status__c,
9, US_School__r.X4th_Grade_Status__c, 
10, US_School__r.X3rd_Grade_Status__c, 
11, US_School__r.X2nd_Grade_Status__c, 
12, US_School__r.X1st_Grade_Status__c, 
13, US_School__r.Kindergarten_Grade_Status__c, 
'Graduated')
```

Basically, if we reach the situation where we'd start with 4, we add 1, otherwise add nothing. This formula should be half the compiled size or better. I can't say if it'll definitely solve your problem, but it's a start.

Comment: How do I vote best answer so @sfdcfox can get credit?